# "The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first" when replace fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, replace, android-nested-fragment, fragmentmanager

First I want to explain my layout. It is a "tab list in a tab" which means a list view is controlled by a tab and the tab list is controlled by another tab. Hope you can understand what I mean...

my two tab widgets:

(bottom tab: main control panel)

```
public class BottomTabWidget extends FragmentActivity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.bottom_tab);

        FragmentTabHost tabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(R.id.bottom_tab_host);

        tabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.bottom_tab_content);

        View exploreView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.explore, null);         
        View browseView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.browse, null);
        View profileView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.profile, null);
        View cartView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.cart, null);

        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("explore").setIndicator(exploreView), ListTabWidget.class, null);        
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("browse").setIndicator(browseView), SearchList.class, null);
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("profile").setIndicator(profileView), SearchList.class, null);
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("cart").setIndicator(cartView), SearchList.class, null);
    }
}
```

(list tab: only control the list view)

```
public class ListTabWidget extends Fragment{

    //for extending Fragment
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedIntanceState){
        //View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_tab, container);

        //FragmentTabHost tabHost = (FragmentTabHost)view.findViewById(R.id.list_tab_host);
        FragmentTabHost tabHost = new FragmentTabHost(getActivity());

        tabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.id.listtabcontent);
        View tabView = setTab(inflater, "  New Items  ");
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("all_post").setIndicator(tabView), ListPost.class, null);

        return tabHost;
    }

    private View setTab(LayoutInflater inflater, String text){
        View tabView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_tab_text, null);
        TextView textView = (TextView)tabView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(text);
        return tabView;
    }
}
```

code in `ListPost` class (too long so I cut out the critical part)

```
listView = (ListView)this.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        list  = new CustomAdapter(this.getActivity() ,android.R.layout.simple_selectable_list_item, productArray);
        listView.setAdapter(list);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
                Product item = (Product) parent.getItemAtPosition(position); 

                Bundle args = new Bundle();             
                args.putString("pid", item.getData(WPTemplateDB.PRODUCT_ID)+"");

                //switchFragment(args);
                new FragmentProcess().switchFragment(getActivity(), R.id.bottom_tab_content, new PostDetail(), args);
            }           
        });
```

`FragmentProcess` class

```
public class FragmentProcess {

    public void switchFragment(FragmentActivity activity, int element, Fragment replaceFragment, Bundle args){
        replaceFragment.setArguments(args);
        FragmentTransaction transaction = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        transaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
        transaction.replace(element, replaceFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

The error (shown as title) occurs when I click the list view elements which means replacing fragment. What I did wrong??

Answer (score 1):

Oh...I was just a silly mistake in `PostDetail` class.

in `onCreateView` I mistype the inflate part, now I correct it to `inflate(R.layout.list_detail, container, false)`

it is runnable now, thanks for bros who are trying to help me....